# Seeing "Couldn't statvfs() path: No such file or directory" when running Android emulator on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android-emulator

When running the emulator from Android Studio 3.3.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 I'm getting the dreaded

`Emulator: Couldn't statvfs() path: No such file or directory`

message in the Event Log. The emulator seems to be running ok.

I've already installed the 32 bit libraries that are required to run Android Studio as per https://developer.android.com/studio/install#linux. My laptop is a Dell XPS 13 9380 with an Intel 915 chipset so the recommendations I found to install nVidia drivers do not apply.

Also tried switching between hardware and software rendering for the emulator, both with the same effect.

Comment: i have the same problem :'(

Comment: same here, I've read multiple OPs with no solution yet that has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This was my video cards driver, Ive updated that for the vendor drivers and works wonderfully